# I use jquery blinking functionality to parent div.but that effects chaild div.please help how to solve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using multiple div tags.for the parent div I used jquery blinking functionality.but that effecting my chaild div tags.
I want to blink only parent div.please help me.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbfUv.png)

Comment: Please post your code, not a link to an image of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` methods from jQuery change `opacity`.

Whenever you change the opacity of an element, ***you change the opacity of all its children.***

This means that a child with `opacity:0.5` placed inside a parent with `opacity:0.5` will be rendered exactly as one with `opacity:0.25` placed inside a parent with `opacity:1`.

There is no way around that, except making its children no longer be its children: Put content into a non-blinking container and the blinking part into a blinking container and make them children of the same parent with `position:relative;`. One of them needs to have `position:absolute` (normally the blinking one, but it depends on context).

Here's an example:

```js
function blink(selector) {
  $(selector).fadeOut(2000, function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(2000, function(){ 
      blink(this)
    })
  })
}
blink($('child[blinking]'));
```

```css
parent, child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

child[blinking] {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

child {
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<parent>
  <child blinking></child>
  <child>
    Place the non-blinking content into a sibling of the blinking element and absolute-position one of them (usually the blinking one).
  </child>
</parent>
```

Comment: I want this.Its worked fine for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @mani, feel free to apply it to your project, no need to ask for my permission. This answer was added so you and others like you learn how what you asked for can be achieved. If it helped you find a working solution or solved your problem, feel free to mark it as accepted answer. Please take some time to read [ask] to learn more about how [SO] functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. If you hide the parent all it's children will hide as well, and the same goes for opacity. You might be able to simulate it depending on what you want to do, but you will have to provide the html code.